# SharePoint 2007 popup

Tags: sharepoint

[image: Content Editor Web Part]

In the Content Editor Web Part,we click the Source Editor button,it will popup a webpage dialog,and you can type the html source code in it and save it.
Now,I need to achieve this function in my webpart.I added a js function to my button,

```
myButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "commonShowModalDialog(url,features)");
```

It popups a dialog,but I don't know how to save the contents in the dialog to my webpart.
Any ideas to solve this?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can save popup window's text in webpart property in toolpart.

This property will be accessed in WebPart & ToolPart also.

For WebPart Properties see below example,

```
   [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
   [WebBrowsable(true)] 
   [Category("Display")]
   [WebDisplayName("Popup Text")]
   [Description("You can configure this text from here in popup")]
   public string PopupText 
   { get; set; }
```

add above code in WebPart Class and use this "PopupText" property in assign Literal control OR direct render this property in overwrite Render method.

Comment: That's what I asked,but I don't know how,I don't know the link between the popuped dialog and toolpart.